# Filter @ConfigurationProperties in @Value

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin

I have my property file like this:

```yaml
integrations:
  - operationCode: CD001
    connectionFactoryName: cf1
    senderName: sn1
    host: 192.168.1.1
    port: 1416
    queueManager: QM_TSTIN
    channel: JAVA.CHANNEL
    username: user
    password: pass
    receiveTimeout: 10000
    sendQueue: SEND
    receiveQueue: RECEIVE
```

How can i get my `integration` entity by `operationCode`? This is how i try to do this. But it does not work.

```kotlin
@Value("\${integrations.?[operationCode == 'CD001'].receiveQueue}")
var receiveQueue: String? = null
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible using the property placeholder syntax `${}` and also not possible by the SPEL syntax `#{}` as far as I know.

The property placeholder is a very simple solution it provides direct access `${a.b.c}` with the option of default value `${a.b.c:default_value}`. In terms of syntax that's it ([javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.html)).

The Spring Expression Language is very powerful comparing to the property placeholder but can not access properties directly. You can access a property by `#{'${a.b.c}'}` but the `a.b.c` must be a leaf in the yaml it can not access internal nodes. So you can not use the `#{'${a.b}'.c}` as the `a.b` is an internal node. So even you could use the `#{bean.collection.?[attribute1 > 5].attribute2}` in SPEL you can not use that for properties.

I suggest the standard yml attributes instead of the collection:

```yaml
integrations:
  CD001:
    operationCode: CD001
    receiveQueue: RECEIVER_2
  CD002:
    operationCode: CD002
    receiveQueue: RECEIVER_2
```

and then use the `@Value("${integrations.CD002.receiveQueue}")` to get the value.

Unfortunately as far as I know there is no expression to solve your problem if you can not change the yaml's format.